# Magento google products site html help

Tags: html, magento, oscommerce, product

I am trying to paste a google tag into homepage head tag but i cannot find it on index.php

Where does it go??

Comment: If this question is about Magento (as your title implies), then this doesn't have anything to do with osCommerce.  Why the tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something of the header of every page, it should to go into the template file at `%magento%/app/design/frontend/base/default/page/html/header.phtml`. This file will be included on all the normal pages.

Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Joe